# Coldfusion Log Files and Timezone/Locales

Tags: datetime, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

We have an application that records information into a database and if there is an erorr, we are logging it in a log file.  We have users spread across the globe.  If something does happen, we'd like to record the timestamp of the issue but we need the timestamp to be uniformed meaning someone in Hong Kong vs California, should have the same timestamp with appropriate timezone offset.  I dont know how to do this in CF.

Dealing with dates has always been a week skill set of mine and would appreciate some help figuring this one out.

Here is the code which writes out the log file

```
<cftry>
... insert into db here ...
    <cfcatch type="any"> 
        <cfset error_msg = '#createodbcdatetime(now())#|#cfcatch.Message#|#cfcatch.Detail#|#cgi.HTTP_REFERER#|#cgi.SERVER_NAME#|#cgi.SCRIPT_NAME#|#cgi.QUERY_STRING#'>
        <cftry>
            <cfif FileExists(ExpandPath(#log_name#))>
                <cflock name="WebSiteErrorLog_Lock" type="exclusive" timeout="30">  
                    <cffile action="append" addnewline="yes" file="#currentDirectory##log_name#" mode="777" output="#error_msg#">
                </cflock>
            <cfelse>
                <cflock name="WebSiteErrorLog_Lock" type="exclusive" timeout="30">
                    <cffile action="write" addnewline="yes" file="#currentDirectory##log_name#" mode="777" output="#error_msg#">
                </cflock>
            </cfif>
        <cfcatch type="any"></cfcatch>
    </cftry>
</cfcatch>
```

but this line is probablly all that is really needed for this SO question:

```
<cfset error_msg = '#createodbcdatetime(now())#|#cfcatch.Message#|#cfcatch.Detail#|#cgi.HTTP_REFERER#|#cgi.SER
```

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am curious, are you using ColdFusion 9? Because you may want to look into implementing the OnError function in your Application.cfc. It may be a bit more convenient than this constant Try-Catch approach.

That being said, the following function will return formatted UTC time. I think I stole it from someone else's answer previously on this site.

```
<cffunction name="getUTCTime" access="public">
    <cfscript>
        var serverTime=now();
        var utcTime=GetTimeZoneInfo();
        var utcStruct=structNew();
        utcStruct.Hour=DatePart("h", serverTime);
        utcStruct.Minute=DatePart("n", serverTime);
        utcStruct.Hour=utcStruct.Hour + utcTime.utcHourOffSet;
        utcStruct.Minute=utcStruct.Minute + utcTime.utcMinuteOffSet;
        if (utcStruct.Minute LT 10) utcStruct.Minute = "0" & utcStruct.Minute;
    </cfscript>
    <cfreturn utcStruct.Hour & ":" & utcStruct.Minute>
</cffunction>
```

**Update:**

As mentioned in the comments, the above code is unnecessary and buggy. Its preferable to use the built-in [dateConvert()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6dd4.html) function (available since at least MX7):

```
<cfset timeString = timeFormat( dateConvert("local2utc", now()), "HH:mm")>
```

Comment: The application is an older app and isn't setup with Application.cfc

Comment: oh well. that's disappointing.. but the cffunction should still work, at least in CF8 and later versions..

Comment: Ah, you are absolutely correct!  I was able to use this with the version of CF we are running.  Thanks!

Comment: If you are using Application.cfm, there is an onError template available.

Comment: @XaxD - Yeah, but that will return wrong results later in the day, for example: 26:42. Why not just use [`dateConvert`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6dd4.html), then format however you want?

Comment: @leigh you may be right. really all he needs is serverTime=now(); like i said i lifted this script from here on stackoverflow, I didn't write/test it.

Comment: With simple code snippets, you should always test them before posting (when possible). If you cannot, at least mention it is *not* tested, so the asker does not waste a lot of time on it if there is a problem :) Since answers are archived, would you mind updating your response with the correct code? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I just revised it a little to show the progression of the answer and preserve context. Hope you do not mind :)